# I am trying to select certain measurements that were taken at Noon using Lubridate and Tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

So I load in my data into R and load the libraries that I believe I will be needed:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

getRiceData <- function() {
url <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mk1YGH9LqjF7drJE-td1G_JkdADOU0eMlrP01WFBT8s/pub? 
gid=0&single=true&output=csv"

data <- read.csv( url , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

library(lubridate)

format <- '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'

data$Date <- parse_date_time( data$DateTime,
                          orders = format,
                          tz = "EST" ) 


data$Airtemp <- 5/9 * ( data$AirTempF - 32 )
data$Rain <- data$Rain_in * 25.4
data$WindSpeed <- data$WindSpeed_mph * 1.60934

data$AirTempF <- data$DateTime <-
data$Rain_in <- data$PH_mv <- 
data$BGAPC_rfu <- data$Depth_ft <- 
data$SurfaceWaterElev_m_levelNad83m <-
NULL

return( data )
}
```

Next step

```
`source("getRiceData.R")
data <- getRiceData()
summary(data)`
```

Now I will like to select only measurements taken at noon. How would I go about doing this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the best way to do it, but you could try:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(data, substr(Date, 12, 20) == "12:00:00")
```

You may need to be careful if the dates are not all in the same time zone, perhaps because of Daylight Savings Time, depending on exactly what you mean by "noon".